# Make MacOS always offer "external headphones" whether or not attached

Tags: audio, headphones

Some audio editing software I use does device enumeration at startup time, and cannot be told to rescan for new devices without restarting.

This would not particularly be a problem, but for the built-in 3.5mm headphone jack (on my 2021 MacBook Pro) only showing up as an available output device when a pair of headphones are actually plugged in.

Is it possible to work around this behavior on the MacOS side, configuring the operating system to *always* consider the audio jack to be an available output device whether or not there are headphones attached?

Comment: I believe plugging in any kind of adapter will trip the switch inside the port to “trick” the computer into thinking there are headphones attached.  This will leave something sticking out the port, which I assume is undesirable, but better than leaving a headphone cord dangling off.  I recall a means to create an audio device that can “pass through” to the headphone jack but not in sufficient detail for an answer.  Perhaps this will jog someone’s memory as it may not come to mind right away as it is a bit obscure.